# list of price dictionaries to one price dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to convert this list of dicts to one dictionary

```
currency = [{'symbol': 'IDR', 'value': 7.1e-05}, {'symbol': 'VND', 'value': 4.4e-05}, {'symbol': 'MYR', 'value': 0.25}, {'symbol': 'CNY', 'value': 0.15}, {'symbol': 'SGD', 'value': 0.76}, {'symbol': 'GBP', 'value': 1.42}, {'symbol': 'INR', 'value': 0.014}, {'symbol': 'CAD', 'value': 0.8}, {'symbol': 'BRL', 'value': 0.18}, {'symbol': 'EUR', 'value': 1.22}, {'symbol': 'BOB', 'value': 0.14}, {'symbol': 'COP', 'value': 0.00028}, {'symbol': 'CLF', 'value': 41.75}]
```

I tried some comprehension techniques to convert it

```
{k:v for element in currency for k,v in element.items()} # only last element comes back
{n1:n2 for n1,n2 in i.values() for i in currency} #error
```

I am looking a one liner which does this, expected output is

```
{'IDR': 7.1e-05, 'VND': 4.4e-05, 'MYR': 0.25, 'CNY': 0.15, 'SGD': 0.76, 'GBP': 1.42, 'INR': 0.014, 'CAD': 0.8, 'BRL': 0.18, 'EUR': 1.22, 'BOB': 0.14, 'COP': 0.00028, 'CLF': 41.75}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One liner with dict comprehension as:

```
res = {elt['symbol']: elt['value'] for elt in currency}
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'IDR': 7.1e-05, 'VND': 4.4e-05, 'MYR': 0.25, 'CNY': 0.15, 'SGD': 0.76, 'GBP': 1.42, 'INR': 0.014, 'CAD': 0.8, 'BRL': 0.18, 'EUR': 1.22, 'BOB': 0.14, 'COP': 0.00028, 'CLF': 41.75}
```

Comment: this works, can I ask why `{n1:n2 for n1,n2 in i.values() for i in currency}` doesn't work
I tried `n1,n2 = currency[0].values()` this works but it doesn't in comprehension

Comment: `i.values()` is a list so you can't iterate using `for n1, n2 in i.values()`. with `n1,n2 = currency[0].values()` you are taking out first two elements and assigning it to `n1` and `n2`